# 2 different literal array declaration in object reference each other

Tags: javascript, object

i want to know how in this obj when it declare and use 2 literal array they both reference each other

```
var o = {
    push:[].push,
    length:0,
    toString:[].join,
    valueOf:function(){
    return arguments[0] == "number" ? this.length : this.toString();
   }
};

o.push(1, 2, 3);

o.toString(); // "1,2,3"
(o*1).toString(); // 3
```

Nothing it is an fundamental i think

no need code

how 2 different literal array reference each other

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hi Thanks I corrected it! I just used to use backtick so ... - what do you mean by seventh undeleted question?

Comment: This is the seventh question listed on your profile. If you also wrote others but you've since deleted them (or the community has), I obviously wouldn't know about them. :-)

Comment: Some one please take the negative rate out from my question

Answer (score 0):

The two arrays aren't referencing each other. In fact, neither of those arrays exists anymore once you've created `o`. You're just creating them, getting a reference to their `push` and `join` methods, and then throwing away the arrays. Those methods have no link back to the arrays you got them from.

The reason you see what you're seeing is that `push` is using `o`, not the arrays you got the methods from. (`push` works just fine if you call it on a non-array; most array methods do).

Here's a simpler situation demonstrating the same concept:

```js
var obj1 = {
    setValue: function(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
};
var obj2 = {
    setValue: obj1.setValue,
    showValue: function() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
};

obj2.setValue(42);
obj2.showValue(); // 42
```

`setValue` sets the value on `obj2`, not `obj1`, because it was called as `obj2.setValue(42)`.

More:

- [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Look, i think i fully grasp the THIS concept. The example you provided is clear. Problem was that i didn't realized that push and join now freely do the same job in object literal as it is a array!!! That you mentioned it now " push is using o, not the arrays you got the methods from. (push works just fine if you call it on a non-array; most array methods do "

Comment: Btw, really these push and join do the same in object, it means they put values as properties in the object properties or just create a new array in object and work on that?

Comment: and more, the length property automatically increase to 3? not only 2, but 3? 1 2 3 -> 0 1 2

Comment: @ja0k0010 - They actually do the work with properties on the object (`o`). Standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *(that's a link to a post on my blog)*, they're just objects that have a particular prototype and special behavior for a class of properties named in a particular way ("array indexes") and a special `length` property.

Comment: @ja0k0010 - You pushed three entries into the object, so yes, its `length` is `3` (it wasn't *automatic*, `push` did that).